# Drop Down Checkbox Open and Close

Tags: html, css

I have built a dropdown checklist but cannot figure out how to close the dropdown.

At the moment it just displays as open.

What I want it to do is behave like a normal drop down.  click to open, click off the dropdown or in the placeholder to close.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards
Max

This is the markup:

```
                               <li class="options">
                                <input type="text" name="locations" placeholder="Preferred Locations" required/>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="locations_op"><label>Option1</label></li>
                                    <li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="locations_op"><label>Option2</label></li>
                                    <li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="locations_op"><label>Option3</label></li>
                                </ul>
                                <div class="bottom"></div>
                            </li>
```

This is the css:

```
.form input {border:1px solid #BBABA9;}
            .form li.options {position:relative;}
            .form li.options ul {
                width: 93%;
                position:relative;
                z-index:2;
                margin: 0 auto;
                border-radius: 5px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
                -moz-border-radius: 5px;
                -ms-border-radius: 5px;
                -o-border-radius: 5px;
                text-align: left;
            }
            .form .options li{
                width: 100%;
                line-height:1em;
                padding: 7px 15px;
                border-radius: 5px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
                -moz-border-radius: 5px;
                -ms-border-radius: 5px;
                -o-border-radius: 5px;
                text-align: left;
                border:1px solid #BBABA9;
                margin:0 auto;
                background:#F2F0F0;
                background-color:#F2F0F0;
                -webkit-margin-before: 0;
                -webkit-margin-after: 0;
                -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
                -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                -webkit-padding-start: 18px;
            }
            .form .options li:hover{
                background:#162654;
                background-color:#162654;
                color:#ffffff;
            }
            input[type=checkbox]{
                /*-ms-transform: scale(1.5);*/ /* IE */
                -moz-transform: scale(1.5); /* FF */
                /*-webkit-transform: scale(1.5);*/ /* Safari and Chrome */
                -o-transform: scale(2); /* Opera */
            }
            .form .options .checkbox{
                width:21px;
                height:21px;
                margin:0 10px 0 0;
                vertical-align:middle;
                padding:0;
            }
            .form .options label{font-size:0.875em;}
            .form .options .bottom{
                width:92.9%;
                height:30px;
                background:#303030;
                background-color:#303030;
                border-radius: 5px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
                -moz-border-radius: 5px;
                -ms-border-radius: 5px;
                -o-border-radius: 5px;
                margin:0 auto;
                position:relative;
                z-index:1;
                bottom:15px;
                border:1px solid #766E6D;
                margin-bottom:-15px;
                -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
                -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
```

Comment: I think you will need to add javascript code to accomplish this.

Comment: Hi Nathan.  Im a bit scared of javascript.  Do you know which code i should use?

Comment: u mean something like this press on place holder http://jsfiddle.net/APA2S/4563/

Comment: @MaxC jQuery would be the easiest. You should really learn javascript btw. However, I understand that it takes a long time. Give me a sec to create a fiddle for you

Comment: I know I need to learn java script.  But im just getting my head around css.  And although rewarding it is extremely challenging for me:)

Comment: @MaxC Yup I understand that. Have you tried [codecademy](http://codecademy.com)? That's where I learned to code. It's a great website. Check out the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/phy2ztee/

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="dropdown" class="options" style="display:none">

    <input type="text" name="locations" placeholder="Preferred Locations" required="required">
   <ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="locations_op"><label>Option1</label></li>
       <li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="locations_op"><label>Option2</label></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="locations_op"><label>Option3</label></li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div id="clickme">Click Me!</div>
```

You need to manually position your dropdown where you want it, however.

Eg.

```
#dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    left:100px;
}
```

Or something like that. If you need help positioning, just leave a comment.

If you want smoother animations, leave a comment. Right now it will fade in and out.

Comment: That's awesome Nathan!  Thanks very much.  Im now looking at codecademy.  Cheers for that.